# Clojure invokeLater null pointer

Tags: swing, concurrency, clojure

This code:

```
(import 'javax.swing.SwingUtilities)
(SwingUtilities/invokeLater (print "hi"))
```

Causes this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
...
```

I don't know if this is a problem, since the code *itself* actually works (printing to the REPL) despite the error.

However, modifying swing components does not seem to work properly: a carot listener that call back (.setText myTextArea "some text") causes the text to alternate between "some text" and setting it to empty when clicked on, each time throwing the same error in the nrepl-server's log.

Is there something wrong with how invoke later is called or is the problem with myTextArea unrelated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwingUtilities/invokeLater takes a `Runnable`. Clojure functions implement Runnable. However you're passing the results of `(println "Hi")` which is `nil` to invokeLater, hence the NPE. You need to pass it as a function to be called, instead of calling it yourself. This example passes an anonymous function to invokeLater.

```
(import 'javax.swing.SwingUtilities)
(SwingUtilities/invokeLater #(print "hi"))
```